# How to call onClick function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, onclick

I use jQuery validation plugin.  When validator.checkForm() is true, onclick function in serverSide doesn’t call. How toa call changepass_Click fucntion?
I debug it but after click , page reloads and doesn't go to changepass_Click fucntion.
It's my html:

```
<div id="changePassDiv" runat="server" style="visibility: hidden; height: 85px;">
                <fieldset id="changePassFieldset" runat="server">
                    <legend>legend</legend>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span>password</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="currentPass" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span>new password</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="newPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                            <td style="text-align: center">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnValidate" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/send-50x20.png" BackColor="#a1c854"
                                    Height="20px" CssClass="btnpadding1" Width="50px" OnClick="changepass_Click" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: center">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnReturn" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/return-50x20.png" BackColor="#a1c854"
                                    Height="20px" CssClass="btnpadding1" Width="50px" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <ul id="ErrorSection" class="validateError" runat="server">
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
```

It's my jquery:

```
        var validator = $('.form').validate({
            rules: {
                <%= currentPass.UniqueID %>: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 25
                }

            },
            errorClass: "error-label",
            wrapper: "li",
            errorLabelContainer: "#ErrorSection",
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                console.log(form)
                $(form).submit();
            }
        });
        $("#btnValidate").click(function (e) {
            if (!validator.checkForm()){
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `e.preventDefault();` from the click event handler and it should work fine.

Check what [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) does.